# Insert into table when one value not exist in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I have two tables, they have a same column `id`, but `table1` has more `id`s than `table2`. Now I want to find those `id`a in `table1` but not exist in `table2`, and `insert` them into `table2`, and set their value of count as 0.

I tried the following code but it says `syntax error, unexpected IF`.

```
if not exists(select * from table1 where table1.id = table2.id)
begin
    insert into table2 (id, count) values (table1.id, 0)
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with a single `insert . . . select` statement:

```
insert into table2(id, count)
    select id, 0
    from table1 t1
    where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id);
```

I am guessing that you are using MySQL if you are getting an error on `if` (`if` is only allowed in procedure/function/trigger code).  But even if `if` where allowed, the query in `exists` references `table2.id` and there is no `table2` in the `from` clause.  So that would be the next error.

Answer (score 2):

LEFT JOIN also could be used here

```
insert into table2(id, count)
select t1.id, 0
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.id is null;
```

Comment: I think this is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id,count)
SELECT id,0 from table1 where id NOT IN (select id from table2)
```